# Command line options for Windows 11 installation assistant

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade few Windows 10 devices by running [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) command line options but none of the combinations seem to work.

[image]

I've gone through the binary and see below commands/parameters available but keep getting EULA.

```
Launching target executable
/Push
/Install
/SetupFile
/SkipSelfUpdate
/ReUseCatalog
/SkipEULA
/OobeUi
/OobeRS2Ui
/EosUi
/PostEosUi
/TenSUi
/SunValley
/PreventWUUpgrade
/SetOobeTourniquetRunningRegKey
/SetPriorityLow
/UninstallUponExit
/UninstallUponUpgrade
/ForceUninstall
/MinimizeToTaskBar
/ShowProgressInTaskBarIcon
/SkipCompatCheck
/QuietInstall
/NoRestartUI
/EnableTelemetry
/InstallationFolder
/Edition
/Language
```

Has anyone done this already ?

Comment: Why do you believe the Upgrade Assistant supports those arguments? I would expect those only to work with the setup.exe contained on the ISO

Comment: @Ramhoud I usually go through the exe to see the available commands and these are the switches I see in it. The same process worked with Windows 10 update assistant and I expect them to work with Windows 11 installation Assistant as well.

Comment: They appear to be very different executables. The fact one is an installation assistant tells me it’s different than the upgrade assistant.  Which likely will come back for 22H2